# VB6 - Sending data to Telnet

Tags: string, vb6, telnet, packet

I've been looking around for some code examples for sending data from a server application in VB6 to Telnet. From what I've seen (Baring in mind these code examples are 15-20 years old), you can only send raw strings?

I'm just playing around with some source code I made, where I have a custom stand-alone client, so I'm sending byte arrays back and forth to handle strings and values. I'm worried that only being able to send raw strings will massively reduce network performance between the server and client.

Are there any other examples?

Currently I send messages like this:

```
Public Sub SendMsg(ByVal Index As Long, ByVal Msg As String)
Dim Buffer As clsBuffer
   
    Set Buffer = New clsBuffer
    Buffer.PreAllocate Len(Msg) + 4
    Buffer.WriteInteger SSendMsg
    Buffer.WriteString Msg
    
    Call SendDataTo(Index, Buffer.ToArray)
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

The code there is what I currently have to send data to a custom client, not Telnet. *My question is, is it possible to send that type of data to Telnet?*

Comment: You might want to check out [VbAsyncSocket](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket) repo's samples for a more modern approach to network sockets in VB6 incl. `Winsock Control` replacement and `WinHttpRequest Object` replacement with built-in TLS 1.3 support (outside of OS provided native SSPI/Schannel impl).

Comment: LGTM, provided that `clsBuffer` abstracts a byte-array and provides helper methods to read/write primitive types. A class is a bit too heavy and I usually prefer a UDT with only Buffer byte-array and Size/Position integer members to work on I/O streams (un)packing.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NzkHxnZg

Comment: @SteveJones [Here](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/src/mdTlsThunks.bas#L4709-L4857) is somewhat lightweight impl (UDT based)